# 16 color palette bmp files in asm

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bmp

im working on a project that requires me to print a 16 color palette bmp file using assembly (8086), i found this code online that works printing files that have 256 color palettes, and i would like to know if someone can help me to modify it so it can print 16 color palette bmps

im working with 640x480 images(the code already works with those dimensions)
i found the code here: [netLoad Bitmaps (16-bit ASM)](https://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/articles/article202.html)

i really havent tried anything because i dont understand the code well.

i also found this question [How to print BMP photo file in assembly graphics mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570102/how-to-print-bmp-photo-file-in-assembly-graphics-mode). this code also works on 256color bmps but with a 320*200 res, so idk if this is easier to modify to achieve what i need.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
_DATA segment word public 'DATA'
filename  db   'file.BMP',0  ; insert the name and location
GLEN        db   'Programmed by Glen Quinn, BINARY SOFTWARE' ; of the bitmap here
          db   '$'

handle    dw   ?           ; handle is used to store the file pointer
X         dw   ?           ; X and Y is used to fill the screen with pixels
Y         dw   ?
col       db   640 dup(?)  ; col is used as a buffer to do a screen line
                           ; at a time
buff      dw   0
          dw   0
          dw   0
          dw   0
multi     dw   6
          dw   4
          dw   0
          dw   0
num       dw   0
l         dw   409         ; l is used to store where the banks break up
          dw   408
          dw   307
          dw   306
          dw   204
          dw   203
          dw   102
          dw   101

BMPHEAD    struc           ; This is the bitmap structure
   id          db   2 dup(?)
   filesize    dw   2 dup(?)
   reserved    dw   2 dup(?)
   headersize  dw   2 dup(?)
   infosize    dw   2 dup(?)
   width       dw   2 dup(?)
   depth       dw   2 dup(?)
   biplanes    dw   ?
   bits        dw   ?
   bicomp      dw   2 dup(?)
   bisizeim    dw   2 dup(?)
   bixpels     dw   2 dup(?)
   biypels     dw   2 dup(?)
   biclrused   dw   2 dup(?)
   biclrimp    dw   2 dup(?)
BMPHEAD   ends

RGBQUAD   struc            ; This is how the bitmap stores its colours
   blue        db   ?
   green       db   ?
   red         db   ?
   fill        db   ?
RGBQUAD   ends

params BMPHEAD <> ; assigning the structures to these values
param    RGBQUAD <>
_DATA ends
.code
start:
   mov  ax,@data ; moving all data into required memory position
   mov  ds,ax

   call loadbmp  ; calls a procedure called loadbmp

   mov  ah,00h   ; waits for a key to be pressed
   int  16h

   mov  ah,00h   ; changes the video mode to the normal setting
   mov  al,02h
   int  10h

   mov  ah,09h       ; Prints out a message on the screen
   mov  dx,offset GLEN
   int  21h

   mov  ah,4ch   ; ends the program
   mov  al,0
   int  21h

putpixel    proc    near  ; this procedure is for putting a single pixel any
                            ; where on the display plane
; The linear address of the display plane is=l*640+x
   mov  ax,Y ; calculating linear=l*640 in 16-bit
   mul  multi
   mov  buff,ax   ; first 16-bit calculation
   mov  ax,100
   mul  buff
   mov  buff,ax
   mov  buff+2,dx

   mov  ax,Y    ; secound 16-bit calculation
   mul  multi+2
   mov  buff+4,ax
   mov  ax,10
   mul  buff+4
   mov  buff+4,ax
   mov  buff+6,dx

   mov  ax,buff ; now adding the two 16-bit values
   add  ax,buff+4
   mov  buff,ax
   mov  ax,buff+2
   adc  ax,buff+6
   mov  buff+2,ax

   mov  ax,X  ; now adding x to the expression
   add  buff,ax
   adc  buff+2,0   ; expression is now lin=l*640+x

   mov  ax,buff
   mov  dx,buff+2

   mov  cx,16       ; calculating bank number
F1: sar dx,1
        rcr ax,1
      loop  F1
        mov num,ax

      mov   ax,l    ; testing each of the bank boundaries
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

        mov   ax,l+2
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

      mov   ax,l+4
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

      mov   ax,l+6
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

      mov   ax,l+8
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

      mov   ax,l+10
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

      mov   ax,l+12
      cmp   ax,Y
      je        pass

      mov   ax,l+14
      cmp   ax,Y

      jne   bypass
pass:
   mov ah,4fh   ; adjusting the bank
    mov al,05h
    mov bh,00h
    mov bl,00h
    mov dx,num
    int 10h

bypass:

    mov ax,0A000h      ;writing a single pixel to the display
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,buff
    mov di,ax
    mov al,[si]
    stosb  ; writing pixel ends
    inc si
    ret
    endp

loadbmp proc    near  ;this procedure is for loading in the bitmap
   mov ah,4fh ; set mode to SVGA (101h i.e 640X480 in 256 colours
   mov al,02h
   mov bx,101h
   int 10h

   mov ah,4fh
   mov al,05h
   mov bh,00h
   mov bl,00h
   mov dx,4
   int 10h
   
   mov  ah,3dh   ; file open
   mov  al,00
   mov  dx,offset filename
   int  21h       ; file open end

   mov  handle,ax

   mov  ah,3fh   ; file read
   mov  bx,handle
   mov  cx,54
   mov  dx,offset params
   int  21h      ; file read end

   mov  col,0  ; reading in the palette
G1:
   mov  ah,3fh
   mov  bx,handle
   mov  cx,4
   mov  dx,offset param
   int  21h
   mov  al,col
   mov  dx,3c8h
   out  dx,al
   mov  al,param.red
   shr  al,2
   mov  dx,3c9h
   out  dx,al
   mov  al,param.green
   shr  al,2
   out  dx,al
   mov  al,param.blue
   shr  al,2
   out  dx,al
   cmp  col,255
   inc  col
   jne  G1        ; palette read ends

   mov  Y,479
   mov  X,0
A1:
   mov  ah,3fh   ; file read
   mov  bx,handle
   mov  cx,640
   mov  dx,offset col
   int  21h      ; file read end

   ; writing a single pixel to the display in SVGA
mov si,offset col
A2:
   call  putpixel
   inc  X
   cmp  X,640
   jne  A2
   mov  X,0
   dec  Y
   cmp  Y,-1
   jne  A1

   mov  ah,3eh
   mov  bx,handle
   int  21h
   ret
loadbmp endp
end start
```

Comment: Found where?  You should always credit other people with a link or at least a name when you repost their code.